# Updating pgsnapshot database with osmosis - unable to read state from the server

Tags: openstreetmap, update, osmosis

I set up a local postgis database with osmosis using pgsnapshot schema as described [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/PostGIS_Setup).

The problem occurs when I try to update the database with latest minutely change sets as described [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm/diffs).

When I run the command `osmosis --rri --wxc something.gz` (which is supposed to put all the changes between the previous sequence number and the most up-to-date into the file something.gz ) I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Thread for task 1-rri failed
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Unable to read the state from the server.
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.replication.common.ServerStateReader.getServerState(ServerStateReader.java:116)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.replication.common.ServerStateReader.getServerState(ServerStateReader.java:50)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.replication.v0_6.BaseReplicationDownloader.runImpl(BaseReplicationDownloader.java:290)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.replication.v0_6.BaseReplicationDownloader.run(BaseReplicationDownloader.java:383)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://planet.openstreetmap.org/minute-replicate/state.txt
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.replication.common.ServerStateReader.getServerState(ServerStateReader.java:97)
        ... 4 more
```

Comment: Seems like the correct URL of the minutely state file is *http://planet.osm.org/replication/minute/state.txt*.

Comment: Yes, that was the url where I got the initial state. The url in configuration.txt which osmosis setup itself was the one found in exception.
I changed it to  planet.osm.org/replication/minute/ and it appears to have worked.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command `osmosis --rrii` creates a file `configuration.txt` with a wrong url apparently. Changing it to  `planet.osm.org/replication/minute/` for minutely updates fixes the problem.

Comment: If this is a bug then consider creating a bug report for osmosis.